# How to leave feedback on an ad now?

Tags: facebook

On recent ad activity (left sidebar, last menu option) there used to be a list with ads you clicked and an option to fill out a survey. That button is now gone. However, Facebook still has "feedback score" for pages, so there still seem to be surveys.

How do I leave feedback for an ad now that the button is gone?

Where can I find more details about this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Here is a link to how [Meta calculates feedback scores](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/527723008585166) You can report an ad you have issues with. You can contact an advertiser. Advertisers can enable surveys if they choose to. You can comment on all ads and business pages subject to [advertisers' settings](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1129470964230971). You can provide feedback on an ad-driven purchase.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Blindspots sometimes facebook asks users about their experience with a company, its ad they clicked. I am curious how this mechanism works, why I have never been asked and how some are able to force this survey to appear. I know how feedback score is calculated, I want to know how facebook decides who to ask to fill out the survey. This survey comes from facebook, not the advertiser.

Comment: I see what you are saying. That is good clarification which should typically be an [edit] to your question rather than a comment.  FYI the statement *"some are able to force this survey to appear"* should be substantiated if included in your question.  As it stands this question would be closed under **`Questions that ask about the internal policies, technologies, and algorithms of web application companies are off-topic because only the company or its developers truly know the answer.`**